# Windows forms design mode universal solution

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer, designmode

TL;DR: **Is there an universal solution for the well-known design-mode problem in Windows Forms?**

Windows Forms form design relies heavily on visual designer, which then generates proper initialization code (in contrast to, say, WPF, where window layout is designed declaratively). The problem is, that some of the code shouldn't run if window or control is in design mode (say, loading data from database).

There are some well-known solutions to this problem, but all works only partially:

- `Component.DesignMode` - works only on top-level controls (won't work in a control placed on a control) and doesn't work at all in constructors (where actually it is needed most)
- `LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime` - in turn works only in constructurs (so won't work - say - in `OnPaint` method
- Checking for current process being `devenv.exe` - what is, let's be honest, more of a painful workaround than solid, deterministic, working method

I've been wondering, if there's a way to deterministically and repeatably verify if control or form is in debug mode?

The only solution I've come with would be to create specific configuration for design mode only, set a compilation variable and use conditional compilation:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
#ifndef Design
    ...
#endif
}
```

The problems are:

- This needs to be switched manually
- If you forget to switch configuration back to Debug or Release, half of the application will probably stop working. However one may solve it by stopping build quickly in Main method:

  ```
  static void Main()
  {
  #ifdef Design
      #error Exit design configuration first!
  #endif
  }
  ```

References:

1. http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html

Comment: Interesting, but more the start of a discussion than a real question. Not sure if this is on-topic here.

Comment: There is a universal solution, the one that the XAML designers so relentlessly force you to pursue: separate the view from the model.  But it is not the Winforms way, no MVC framework ever became dominant and the appeal of not being forced into a design pattern and write spaghetti whenever you deem it useful to arrive at RAD has never really waned.  Rather the opposite, it is very agile.  Just don't look for a global solution to a *very* localized problem, the #if sucks far too much to consider.

Comment: Concrete solutions are always simple, just be sure you can easily find out that you need them.  Design-time exceptions can be very destructive, so be sure to check-in often.  Debugging them is a technique that has to be learned.